# Firefox not opening with webdrivermanager: Response code 500

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using Java 11, Selenium, cucumber project with latest webdrivermanager(5.5.3).

Recently the firefox browser (121 version) is not launching via the tests. Please suggest how to resolve it. I did try setting property to latest downloaded geckodriver. Still same issue. Also tried invalidate cache on the IDE and unistalled and installed the latest firefox.

```
    private static FirefoxOptions setupFirefoxOptions() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/<user>/Downloads/geckodriver");

        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
//        firefoxOptions.setBinary("/Users/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox");
        firefoxOptions.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);

        return firefoxOptions;
    }
```

The following is the trace logs from geckodriver.

```
1704383041399   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:63769
1704383041517   geckodriver::capabilities   DEBUG   Trying to read firefox version from ini files
1704383041520   geckodriver::capabilities   DEBUG   Found version 121.0
1704383041533   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_NO_REPORT="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN="1" MOZ_NO_REMOTE="1" "/App ... s" "localhost" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/var/folders/bz/194z010j5yn4zyt048xstkv9gw54lw/T/rust_mozprofileCAlP2I"
1704383041629   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG   Waiting 60s to connect to browser on 127.0.0.1
1704383041629   geckodriver::browser    TRACE   Failed to open /var/folders/bz/194z010j5yn4zyt048xstkv9gw54lw/T/rust_mozprofileCAlP2I/MarionetteActivePort
1704383041629   geckodriver::marionette TRACE   Retrying in 100ms
1704383041734   geckodriver::browser    DEBUG   Browser process stopped: signal: 9 (SIGKILL)
1704383041735   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 500 Internal Server Error {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Process unexpectedly closed with status signal","stacktrace":""}}
Could not use local web driver for reason : Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'HOLBMAC2296', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14e3:a873:b17d:cdb1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.6.1', java.version: '11.0.20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {log: {level: trace}}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {log: {level: trace}}}}]
      java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: update to the latest version and see if the problem is still there

Comment: I've installed the latest firefox, in the IDE did invalidate cache and restarted and also tried to setBinary for Firefox. Nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade Firefox to 119 for the automation to work.